# CSS Hover div triggering effect on no-child div

Tags: html, css, hover

I am looking for a solution for my css hover problem.

I have this HTML

```css
#guia {
  background-image: url(../imgs/guia.png);
  height: 40vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#celulose {
  background-image: url(../imgs/celulose.png);
}
```

```html
<div id="page">

  <div id="top">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <div class="celuloseHover">
        <div>
          <div>
            <p>A Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
          </div>
          <div id="celulose"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div><!-- #top -->

  <div id="mid" class="rel row">
    <div id="selected">
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="guia"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- #mid -->

</div><!-- #page -->
```

I need to hover .celuloseHover and fade out (opacity:0) #guia (please, don't mind the html structure. I have other effect being triggered, and that is why i got that).

I was able to trigger the transition on child elements (e.g. hover .celuloseHover and fade in .celuloseHover div p), but i can't trigger the hover effect on the #guia...

Is there a way to do that?

thanks.

thanks

Comment: No, that is not possible. You would need to apply `:hover` to `#top`, only then you can select the following sibling `#mid` (and go deeper from that).

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. But I have undesired hover area on the #top... is there a way to go around that?

Comment: By `#guide` do you mean `#guia` ? If so then this is not achievable by only CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not possible in CSS.

You must use JavaScript:

> CSS: apply this styles to #guia:

```
#guia {
 /* yout styles */
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.8s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.8s linear 0s;
    transition:opacity 0.8s linear 0s;
}
```

> JS : function to change opacity to #guia

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fadeGuia(opacity){
    document.getElementById("guia").style.opacity = opacity;
}
</script>
```

> HTML: write something inside #guia otherwise you won't see the effect

```
<div id="guia">
   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 
</div>
```

> HTML: set the mouseover mouseout function to celuloseHover.... or to
>   whatever elemen you like

```
 <div class="celuloseHover" onmouseover="fadeGuia(0)" onmouseout="fadeGuia(1)">
```